# Laravel Task Scheduling Run for Every 30 Seconds but only for run for 30 minutes

Tags: laravel-5

Laravel Task Scheduling Run for Every 30 Seconds but only for running for 30 minutes.

It means It totally will run 60 times.

How to set the limit in Task Scheduling?

Comment: Task scheduling has a minimum time of 1 min. It can't run things every 30 sec.

Comment: let's say i want to run in 1 minute. how can I set the limit?

Comment: you can use the ->cron('* * * * * *') option. Its not the nicest solution, but (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,9,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30 0 * * *), will run a task every minute for the first 30mins after midnight

Comment: If you need 60 times, then (* 0 * * *) will run every minute for first 60 mins after midnight

Comment: I am writing an API call, when the API first trigger, I need the API run 60times. Then it will stop trigger it. Should I use Cron? or any other solution?

Comment: Task scheduling is designed to run at a specific time, it might not be the best solution for this. You could create a job queue and put 30 jobs in the queue all with different start times. Does the start time need to be exact? https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues

Comment: The start time is when the job is created / API trigger, it will create a new task. It is trigger to check for the server response. If the server had response. It shall no need continue the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit to answer comment

If you are polling a server for a response every minute until success or 30mins has passed.

Just queue 1 job, in that job handle method

```
public function handle()
{
   // do work
   $response_success = function_to_check_server();

    if (!$response_success && $this->attempts() < 60) {
        $this->release(1); // release back to queue for retry attempt
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, let's say between 30minutes, I got a response from the server, How can I delete the pending job?

Comment: Where you do you set the time run every minute from the code? or job is will be dispatch every minute?

Comment: The first time you dispatch a job onto the queue, it will run straight away, if it fails, then you release it back onto the queue, and make it available 1 minute later eg $this->release(1)